# Extract number embedded in string

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

So I run a `curl` command and `grep` for a keyword.

Here is the (sanitized) result:

```
...Dir');">Town / Village</a></th><th><a href="javascript:SetFilter(3,'ListPublicASDF','ASDFDir');">Phone Number</a></th></tr><tr class="rowodd"><td><a href="javascript:calldialog('ASDF','&Mode=view&helloThereId=42',600,800);"...
```

I want to get the number 42 - a command line one-liner would be great.

- search for the string `helloThereId=`
- extract the number right beside it (42 in the above case)

Does anyone have any tips for this? Maybe some regex for numbers? I'm afraid I don't have enough experience to construct an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `grep` with `-P` (*Perl-Regexp*) parameter enabled.

```
$ grep -oP 'helloThereId=\K\d+' file
42
$ grep -oP '(?<=helloThereId=)\d+' file
42
```

`\K` here actually does the job of positive lookbehind. `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

**References:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Very nice! It's highlighting 42, but it's still printing the big long string?

Comment: did you enable the `-o` parameter?

Comment: Actually, it works now. I was using "-P". It works perfectly with "-oP".

Answer (score 2):

If your **`grep` version supports `-P`**, (as is true for the OP, given that they're on Linux, which comes with *GNU* `grep`), **[Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391191/45375) is the way to go.**

For the potential benefit of future readers, here are alternatives:

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P`, but *does* support `-o`, here's a pragmatic solution that simply extracts the number from the overall match in a 2nd step, by splitting the input into fields by `=`, using `cut`:

```
grep -Eo 'helloThereId=[0-9]+' in | cut -d= -f2 file
```

Finally, if your `grep` supports neither `-P` nor `-o`, use `sed`:
Here's a POSIX-compliant alternative, using `sed` with a *basic* regular expression (hence the need to emulate `+` with `\{1,\}` and to escape the parentheses):

```
sed -n 's/.*helloThereId=\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: You could also use `[0-9][0-9]*` for the same effect without adding messy backslashes

Comment: @JID: Thanks; that's definitely an option in this simple case, but the `\{1,\}` is handy in more complex cases, and it needs better PR :)  (_GNU_ `sed` implements `\+`, which leads people to believe that it's portable, but it's not.)

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any sed on any UNIX OS, even the pre-POSIX default sed on Solaris:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*helloThereId=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file
42
```

Comment: So the pre-POSIX default `sed` on Solaris doesn't support `\{1,\}`? If not, @JID's suggestion should work: using `[0-9][0-9]*` to emulate `+`. (Your solution would match the _empty string_ if `helloThereId=` is _not_ followed by digits, and output `\n`.)

Comment: Correct, putting a backslash before ERE metacharacters to enable their functionality in tools that support BREs was not part of the BRE language until fairly recently. If you stick a backslash before a `{` in Solaris `sed` it's still just a literal `{`. The OP has given us no reason to think there is ever a case where `helloThereId=` is not followed by a number so no reason to complicate the script. If such a case exists the OP should add an input case to show it.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Re complicating the regex: fair point; anyone in true need of the more robust solution can glean it from these comments.

Comment: and thanks for the info that `\+` is not POSIX. Until you mentioned that I had assumed the POSIX decree was that you could stick a backslash in front of any ERE metachar to enable its functionality, I had no idea that `\+` was GNU only (and yes I did have to check it for myself using GNU `sed --posix` before believing it!).